# JQuery to find highest css value among elements and change class

Tags: jquery, css

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="row1"></div>
<div class="row2"></div>
<div class="row3"></div>
<div class="row4"></div>
<div class="row5"></div>
<div class="row6"></div>
<div class="row7"></div>
<div class="row8"></div>
<div class="row9"></div>
<div class="row10"></div>
```

with images inside each div.

Then jQuery that animates the left value for each row:

```
  $( ".row1" ).delay( 600 ).animate({
     left: "580", 
  }, 9000, function() {
  });

 $( ".row2" ).delay( 600 ).animate({
     left: "310", 
  }, 6000, function() {
  });
```

and so on.

Now I'd like to find the row with the highest left value, and change its CSS.

The above code runs when you click a button (moves the rows/images to the right according to the values in the jQuery). So I need to create code that reads the values after that happens, finds the row that has the highest left value (the one that's been moved farthest to the right in other words) and makes that row's `.after` pseudo class visible.

Comment: if you set the left value to the element on your own. you know which element moves the furthest?

Comment: Well, sort of. An intern is going to enter the values, but yes I suppose that means that he could just change the .after to visible in the CSS. Was hoping to just have it automatically calculate and change the CSS, plus I'd sort of like to know how to do that.

Comment: Did this get solved at all?

Comment: Shikkediel   No, I tried your suggestion but wasn't yet able to get it to work, in the meantime the project changed so now I only have five rows to deal with (instead of dozens) so it will be fairly painless to just enter the values manually. If I find time I'll try to get this working, but can't right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheesy and untested, but assuming you have your DIVs in a parent container, I'd find them all, and their position after animation, sort on position and then take the highest one off the list.  Like this:

```
var divs = $('parent > div').map(function(i, o) { return [o.position().left, o]; });
divs.sort(function(a, b) { return a[0] < a[1] ? -1 : a[0] > a[1] ? 1 : 0; });
var highest = divs.pop()[1];
highest.css( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

so you can do.

perhaps you give every of your row classes also one further class for all that elements like:

```
<div class="row row1"></div>
<div class="row row2"></div>
<div class="row row3"></div>
<div class="row row4"></div>
```

than you could do something like this:

```
var mostLeftElement = $();
var mostLeft = null;
$('.row').each(function() {
    mostLeft = Math.max(highest, parseFloat($(this).postion().left));

    if(mostLeft == $(this).postion().left)){
        mostLeftElement = $(this);
    }
});
```

> mostLeft = gives you the left value
>
> mostLeftElement = gives you the element

[$element.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/).left;
gives you the relative left position of the element from its **parent**

while 
[$element.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/).left;
gives you the relative left position of the element from its **document**

hope that helps,
timotheus